# What do the colors on the scrollbar of Jetbrains IDE's mean?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a list that defines what every color in the Intellij Idea scrollbar (right of the screen) means?

Comment: It is the background under the scrollbar, and it is called "Error Stripe". Then combine with the answer, the color of them is "Error Stripe Mark".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find/change it in `Settings` | `Editor` | `Color Scheme`, `General`:

[image: general]

Look for the elements that have **Error Stripe Mark** defined, these are:

- Error
- Warning
- Weak Warning
- Problem from Server
- Identifier under caret
- Text search result
- TODO (default one, can be customized in `Settings` | `TODO` per pattern).

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Community Edition) it's in File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General